# Conditions for equality in the case of calculation of the supremum of $|f|^2$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

It is obvious that $$\sup_{[0,T]}{\left(|f|^2\right)}\leq (\sup_{[0,T]}|f|)^2.$$
My questions is when does the equality hold?

---

*Progress*: If $|f(x)|$ is not the zero function on $[0,T]$, the equality could hold. Let $m=\sup{|f|}$, $\forall \varepsilon >0$, $\exists x_0 \in[0,T]$, s.t. $$f(x_0)>m-\varepsilon>0 $$.  So, $\sup{|f(x)|^2}>(m-\varepsilon )^2$. On the other hand, $\sup{|f(x)|^2}\leq m^2$.  Hence, $$\sup{|f(x)|^2}=m^2$$   Am I right?

Comment: Welcome to math.se! What have you tried so far?

Comment: If $|f(x)|$ is not the zero function on $[0,T]$, the equality could hold.
Let $m=\sup{|f|}$, $\forall \varepsilon >0$, $\exists x_0 \in[0,T]$, s.t. $$f(x_0)>m-\varepsilon>0 $$. 
So, $\sup{|f(x)|^2}>(m-\varepsilon )^2$. On the other hand, $\sup{|f(x)|^2}\leq m^2$.
 Hence, $$\sup{|f(x)|^2}=m^2$$.

Am I right? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equality will always hold.

Let $M = \sup_{[0,T]} |f|$.  For any $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $t \in [0,T]$ with $|f(t)| > M - \epsilon$.

It follows that $|f(t)|^2 > (M - \epsilon)^2$.  So, we have $\sup_{[0,T]} |f|^2 \geq (M-\epsilon)^2$

Thus, we have
$$
\sup_{[0,T]} |f|^2 \geq \sup_{\epsilon > 0}(M-\epsilon)^2 = M^2
$$
That is, we have
$$
\sup_{[0,T]} |f|^2 \geq [\sup_{[0,T]}|f|]^2
$$
which is the opposite direction of the "obvious" equality.  The conclusion follows.

Comment: How did you derived $\sup_{[0,T]} |f|^2 \geq (M-\varepsilon)^2$ from $|f(t)|^2 > (M-\varepsilon)^2$? Since $\sup_{[0,T]} |f|^2 \geq |f(t)|^2$, it implies the strict inequality only.

Comment: Note that $a>b$ implies that $a\geq b$.